# How to run Robotium test on real phone

Tags: android, testing, automation, automated-tests, robotium

I have and compiled .apk (rather than project source files) which I would like to test on my phone with Robotium.

How should I setup test to run it on my phone?

I'm confused because in every tutorial about Robotium these information that I should create an application project and launch the tests from that, but I have only .apk file (which i don't want to modify) and I want only to automate testing it on my phone.

TL;DR

How should I create test case to application which .apk i CAN'T open and it is on REAL device plugged via USB.

Comment: Closed this as a duplicate of a question which seems to also be about testing a finished .apk, not because I'm sure that has your answer, but because yours was one vote short of being absurdly improperly migrated to a different site where it definitely does not belong.  If the answers at the linked question are not applicable to you, please say exactly why and we'll see if we can get this reopened.

Comment: There is no information how to run test on real device, on real phone. They are using Robotium on emulated device, not device plugged via USB

Comment: Not true, the accepted answer there speaks of running on a device, though should work on an emulator as well.  What specific aspect of the process there gave you trouble?

Comment: I'm sorry. But there is no information about "How should I create test case to application which .apk i CAN'T open and it is on REAL device plugged via USB." There are no information about it. Sure, it is possible to run test that was write for application project. But noone said how to write test when I have only .apk. Every tutorial and linked question also shows how to run/create test project when we have Application project. But there is no information about how to create test wjen I have only .apk file on the phone.

Comment: I give up; if you are just going to say the same non-specific thing over and over and refuse to state specifically where the process failed for you (why your attempt to create a parallel test project based on the knowledge of your apk contents failed), you'll have to see what others make of your question.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForAPKFiles

Comment: I'm sorry. My English maybe not good enough to explain this. Ok, I'll try to be more specific. 1. I have .apk file on my phone (.apk is not preinstalled) 2. I don't have any projects in Eclipse. Null, there are no projects. 3. I plugged the phone to PC (USB debugging is ON) 4. Now. What should I do now? There is no infromation about how should I create test project when I don't have application project in Eclipse. 1. How to create black box only test project to test .apk that is only on phone 2. How to write test for this. Every tutorial shows how to create Test Project for Application Project

Comment: Maybe anyone can help me for money via skype + teamviewer or something :( ?

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps

[RobotiumForAPKFiles](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForAPKFiles)

[Blackbox Tutorial 1](https://robotium.googlecode.com/files/TestAndroidCalculatorAPK-BlackBoxTesting-V1_0.pdf)

[Blackbox Tutorial 2](http://robotium.googlecode.com/files/RobotiumForBeginners.pdf)